# Problem related with solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving old exam papers and am stuck on the following problem:

> Consider the system of ODE
>   $\frac {d}{dx}Y=AY,Y(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
> 2\\ 
> -1
> \end{pmatrix}$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &2 \\ 
>  0&-1 
> \end{pmatrix},Y=\begin{pmatrix}
> y_1(x)\\ 
> y_2(x)
> \end{pmatrix}$.  Then I have to determine which of the following options hold good.
>
> 1. $y_1(x) \to \infty,y_2(x) \to 0\,\,$ as $\,\,x \to \infty$
> 2. $y_1(x) \to 0,y_2(x) \to 0\,\,$ as $\,\,x \to \infty$
> 3. $y_1(x) \to \infty,y_2(x) \to -\infty \,\,$ as $\,\,x \to -\infty$
> 4. $y_1(x),y_2(x) \to -\infty \,\,$ as $\,\,x \to -\infty$ .

My Attempt: Using the eigenvalues of $A$,I get the ODE of the form:
$y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x},$ where $c_1,c_2$ being arbitrary constants to be determined . 
Here,I am stuck.I could not use the fact that $Y(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}$ for finding $c_1,c_2$.

Can someone point me in the right direction with some explanation? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the eigenvalue approach, you would generate eigenvectors with them.

These are shown below as column vectors (is it clear how to generate the eigenvectors). You would write:

$$y(x) = c_1 e^x \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{-x}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

From this, we have two solutions, $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$.

Now, you have two equations, two unknowns and two initial conditions to use for finding $c_1$ and $c_2$.

So, we have:

$$y_1(x) = c_1e^x - c_2e^{-x}$$

$$y_2(x) = c_2e^{-x} $$

From the given ICs, we have:

$$y_1(0) = c_1 - c_2 = 2$$

$$y_2(0) = c_2 = -1$$

So, $c_2 = -1$ and $c_1 = 1$, thus:

$$y_1(x) = e^x + e^{-x}$$

$$y_2(x) = - e^{-x} $$

Can you now answer the four questions?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amzoti.I have got it.Now ,I can do the rest.

Comment: @learner: You are very welcome and glad you got it! Regards

Comment: Nice feedback! +1